# How to simplify this usage of conditionals so that core code doesn't need to be written twice?

Tags: expl3

In my document class, I would like to have an option "load-custom-font-file", which is recorded by the bool variable `\l__myclass_load_custom_font_file_bool`. When this option is enabled, the class shall search if there exist a font configuration file named `myclass.font.tex`, and if so, input that file, otherwise use a preset configuration. The code in my mind looks like the following:

```
\bool_if:NTF \l__myclass_load_custom_font_file_bool
  {
    \file_if_exist_input:nF { myclass.font.tex }
      {
        %% preset configuration
      }
  }
  {
    %% preset configuration
  }
```

My question is that, is there a better way so that I won't have to write `preset configuration` twice? (As the preset configuration is very long and contains several other conditionals, it seems a little inappropriate to store it into a token list and then call it when needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said yourself, you can store it in a macro/token list, and use it later, which is rather easy.  You can also use argument grabbing logic to write the preset configuration only once.  It's a rather common trick when you are doing some conditionals, but you still haven't grabbed the code ahead (for example, it may not exist, for whatever reason).  In your case, you could write it like this:

```latex
\bool_if:NT \l__myclass_load_custom_font_file_bool
  {
    \file_if_exist:nT { myclass.font.tex }
      {
        \input { myclass.font.tex }
        \use_none:nn
      }
  }
\use:n
  {
    %% preset configuration
  }
```

In case the boolean is false, or in case the file doesn't exist, the first block is skipped entirely (note you only have the `T` branches in this example), and you are left with `\use:n { %% preset configuration }`, which will just run the code.

In case the boolean is true *and* the file exists, the file is input, and then you have `\use_none:nn \use:n { %% preset configuration }`.  The `\use_none:nn` removes two items from the input stream, thus removing the preset configuration.

Comment: oops that looks similar to mine:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle _You_ answering with `expl3`? ;-)

Comment: I realise I'm better known for tikz, but I have been practicing this expl3 syntax since 1992, I may get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `\file_if_exist:nTF` is not expandable.

```
\bool_new:N \l__myclass_temp_bool

\file_if_exist:nTF { myclass.font.tex }
  { \bool_set_true:N \l__myclass_temp_bool }
  { \bool_set_false:N \l__myclass_temp_bool }
\bool_lazy_and:nnTF { \l__myclass_load_custom_font_file_bool } { \l__myclass_temp_bool }
  {
     \file_input:n { myclass.font.tex }
  }
  {
     % preset configuration
  }
```

If you have several of these constructs, you'll define a suitable function:

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__myclass_loadfile_or_conf:Nnn
  {
     \file_if_exist:nTF { #2 }
       { \bool_set_true:N \l__myclass_temp_bool }
       { \bool_set_false:N \l__myclass_temp_bool }
     \bool_lazy_and:nnTF { #1 } { \l__myclass_temp_bool }
       {
          \file_input:n { #2 }
       }
       {
          #3
       }
  }
```

and call it like

```
\__myclass_loadfile_or_conf:Nnn \l__myclass_load_custom_font_file_bool
  { myclass.font.tex }
  {
    % preset configuration
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion of `\__myclass_loadfile_or_conf:Nnn` is great, with which one shall not need to write the file name twice.